# Customizing QDialog layout at runtime

Tags: qt, qt4

I have Qt dialogs which need to adjust for a different locale at runtime.
The locale is set once at program startup and doesn't change.

I need to change both the label text and the ORDER of some text input boxes.
eg. Text boxes are day,month,year or month,day,year.

Is there a common/simple way to do this?

(note - it's not a simple date control, it's a complex industry specific thing. The date is just an example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a full automatic way to handle this, it would be too complicated because of a lot of scenarios and requirements.
A simple and intuitive way is to use QStackedWidget and put different layout on separate stacks, activate one stack according to locale at runtime. But how to handle the events or acquire data? embeded UI may help.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like the approach.

Comment: Sorry - new here and I had to go and answer some questions to earn points before I could vote for yours???